# IDA Pro not showing structures, even when they're defined

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, decompiler, hexrays

I have this kind of code:

[image]

I have reversed the struct entirely, and when I try to cast to ClientGame*, instead of:

```
if(mainStruct->something & 2)
```

I see:

[image]

The offsets 0x364, 0x370, and 0x374 are also reversed and each one has the size that IDA wants (0x374 is a `db`, 0x364 and 0x370 are `dd`)

Is there any way to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: After pressing `Y` to cast `mainStruct`, did you press `F5` to refresh the decompilation?

Comment: Yep, I did, and it changes to what you see in the 2nd image.

Comment: Can you please update the second screenshot to show the `int __cdecl ...` line? And can you also include a screenshot of your `ClientGame` struct layout?

Comment: Yes, of course. I also named it: http://puu.sh/aqMfA/9949adecb1.png / http://puu.sh/aqMje/fa3a9c8c6e.png (as you can see, all the fields are exactly as IDA wants them to be)

Comment: The screenshot shows that the function argument is an `int`. You didn't cast it.

Comment: Yeah I did, like I explained in my OP: http://puu.sh/asyx1/bd0ae9dbf9.png